# Put icon next to navigation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Trying to put the span class in the class="dropdown-toggle" so the icon shows more to left and becomes bigger.

Hos it looks now:

[image]

Code:

```
  <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>  Vakt <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bWTwL/1144/)**

```
.dropdown-toggle
 { 
  background:#eee; 
  color:#000; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  padding:15px 10px 15px 40px; 
  display:inline-block;
 }
.glyphicon-ok{display:inline-block; padding-right:10px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add padding to the right of the span:

```
.dropdown-toggle .glyphicon.glyphicon-ok {
padding-right:30px;
}
```

I'm not sure how to make it larger.

Here is another post about making the glyphs bigger [Bigger Glyphicons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478365/bigger-glyphicons)

Comment: The image is a icon from the twitter bootstrap gallery. http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Answer (score 1):

To make it bigger can't you just increase height and width?

```
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="width:150%; height:150%"></span>
```