# Bootstrap search glyphicon height

Tags: search, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to make a simple Bootstrap searchbar  (with bootstrap 3.3.7),  but always the glyphicon-search is more little than the form...

With all Bootstrap navbar examples, the result is the same, as the following :

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: my-searchbar]

Do I really need to add some CSS to that ?

Comment: Yes, use CSS like suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18478365/5115768

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another question.  I was on my work computer, and now at home,  I do the same with bootstrap 3.3.7,  but my glyphicon-search is  in gray ...  not like my previous picture.  I tried to include different bootstrap css, but always gray.   Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

To change size and color of your glyphicon:

```css
.glyphicon-search.white {
    font-size: 1.2em; // slightly bigger
    color: #fff; // white
}
```

In your html

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search white"></i>
```